# XOR complement simplification

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

What is (A⊕B)' simplification?
i know that :

### > (A⊕B)=A'B+AB'

but what is the complement of that expression?

Comment: @KingDuken Yes kinda!

Comment: @KingDuken ok i know that but does that means the answer to my question is (A'+B)(A+B')! my book does not say that...

Comment: @KingDuken. If that is a valid answer you should post it as an answer and then delete your "answer" from comments. It helps to close out a post, especially if the OP accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use De Morgan laws to obtain the expression. I assume that what you want is (A⊕B)' expressed in terms of AND and OR

(A⊕B)'=(A'B+AB')' = [negation of OR]

= (A'B)' (AB')' =   [negation of AND]

= (A''+B') (A'+B'') = [double negation]

= (A+B') (A'+B)